# Adding up numbers in a column staring from end of file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file with one column and I want to add numbers in this column from bottom of the file and print the sum in each line. For example if I have the following numbers:

```
1
2
3 
4
5
6
```

I expect the result to look like this:

```
21(6+5+4+3+2+1)
20(6+5+4+3+2)
18(6+5+4+3)
15(6+5+4)
11(6+5)
6 (6)
```

I could think of the following if I was to add numbers from top to bottom I wonder if there is a way to reverse the order of sum using linux, cat, awk etc. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

```
`cat file.txt | gawk ' { sum+=$1; print sum; }' > Final.file`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ tac file | awk ' { sum+=$1; print sum }' | tac
21
20
18
15
11
6
```

Comment: +1 for the rarely seen `tac` command.  Fortunately, there is no such admonition "Useless use of `tac`"!

Comment: @Ed Morton thanks. I certainly haven't heard of `tac` before!

Comment: @bishop presumably it would be spelled "`tac` fo esu sselesU" :-).

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to see the equation:

```
seq 6 | 
awk '
    {
        sum[NR] = $1
        eq[NR] = $1
        for (i=1; i<NR; i++) {
            sum[i] += $1
            eq[i] = $1 "+" eq[i]
        }
    } 
    END {for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) print sum[i] "(" eq[i] ")"}
'
```

```
21(6+5+4+3+2+1)
20(6+5+4+3+2)
18(6+5+4+3)
15(6+5+4)
11(6+5)
6(6)
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't meant to print the whole equation though that was more to make my point clear. It turned out to be confusing.